# Push notification pending intent extras are null when app is not launched

Tags: android, firebase, android-pendingintent

I'm using the `FCMMessagingService` class, and in on message received method, I'm creating a pending intent for `Activity4.class` and passing the extra value as below.

```
   val openIntent = Intent(this, Activity4::class.java)

   openIntent.putExtra("isPush", true)
```

When a push notification is tapped on, can I get the extra data when the app is in the foreground and background with the logged-in case?

But I'm not receiving this extra data when the app is not launched, or the app is killed and relaunched.

In the manifest, the launcher activity is `LaunchActivity.class`. Here, I can see that pendingIntent and launcher activity are different. How can I get the data in this scenario?